# Django regroup grouper

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have successfully implemented the regroup call in my template to order missed donations by a pickup_id. The goal was to display all the routes where a a missed donation occured, and a list of all the names underneath the route name. Pickup routes can have the same name so I was grouping by pickup_id. When I do that and call {{ route.grouper }} it returns the ID of the pickup of course. How can I call the field 'route' which displays the route name from grouper?

I was trying things like this...

```
{{ route.grouper.route }} 
{{ route.route.grouper }}
```

view

```
missed_routes = Donor.objects.filter(missed='YES').order_by('pickup_id')
```

template

```
{% regroup missed_routes by pickup_id as missed_pickups %}
{% for route in missed_pickups %}
    <p>{{ route.grouper }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for donor in route.list %}
            <li>{{ donor.last_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grouper is just a string, so you have to get name from route instance. Not sure it's gonna work, but try `{{ route.list.0.pickup.name }}` (I assume that pickup is foreign key to Pickup model with name field) instead of `{{ route.grouper }}`

Comment: {{ routes.list.0.route }} did the trick. Long story but it's not a foreign key. Route is one fo the fields I have in the model and it worked. Can you explain to me what the .0 means? Or even link to documentation? I never had to use that before. Thanks for your help!

Comment: .0 is just an index of element on a list. You can use it also on querysets.